# Query about Nested Blocks in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a **jinja2** code in my

> base.html

```
    {% block body %}]
    {% block messages %}
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
    {% for category, message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-
    label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;
    </span></button>
    {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {%endblock messages%}
    {% endblock body %}
```

and in the

> entry.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block body %}
    Body text goes here
    {% endblock body %}
```

The problem is until I  don't manually call **super()** in  the **messages** block from the child template  jinja2 doesn't  display the flash messages. 
I'm a total beginner so I maybe completely wrong about how nested blocks work. Can I call the flashed messages without calling super()?? .

Comment: why not move the `message block` out of the `body block`? that way, your `entry` appends to existing html.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I tried that too. When I do that the flashed message  block is shown above the body which messes up the page.

Comment: This is caused because you redefine (substitute) your `body` block from the  base.html in the entry.html . I agree with the the @senaps you have to move it out or re-think your template's structure.

Comment: Ya or I can keep calling the super() block in every child template

Comment: just move it out of the `body block`, then place your `messages` in a better place. you should make a good place for them to show.

Comment: Yep I'll try that again. Thanks.